# JavaScript Regex to select multi-line html comment

Tags: javascript, html, regex, comments

Suppose I have a HTML comment like this:

```
<!--hello world-->
```

We can get the get the comment with this regex:

```js
var expression = /<!--(.*)-->/g
```

Working example:

```js
var expression = /<!--(.*)-->/g;

console.log(document.querySelector("div").innerHTML.match(expression)[0]);
```

```html
<div>
  <!--hello world-->
</div>
```

But if the comment is multi-line, like this:

```
<!--hello
world-->
```

Then the regex doesn't work.

```js
var expression = /<!--(.*)-->/g;

console.log(document.querySelector("div").innerHTML.match(expression)[0]); // Will throw an error because it could not find any matches
```

```html
<div>
  <!--hello
  world-->
</div>
```

How can I select the multi-line HTML comment?

Comment: Try adding \r\n in your expression, if that doesn't work search for line breaks  in regex. That's really the key issue, matching line break in the middle of the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pattern `[\s\S]*` instead of `.*` to catch all chars, including whitespace. Alternatively, use the `m` flag if you want the `.*` match also newlines.

Use non-greedy pattern `[\s\S]*?` if you expect more than one `<!--...-->` pattern.

Working test case:

```js
var expression = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g;

console.log(document.querySelector("div").innerHTML.match(expression));
```

```html
<div>
  <!--hello world 1-->
  <!--hello
  world 2-->
</div>
```

Output:

```
[
  "<!--hello world 1-->",
  "<!--hello\n  world 2-->"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a newline symbol along with any char.
like this -

```
/<!--(.*\n.*)-->/gm;
```

Comment: With the `m` flag the `.` matches also newlines, so `/<!--(.*)-->/gm;` would be sufficient. However, it fails if there are multiple `<!--...-->` patterns. Also, with `/<!--(.*\n.*)-->/gm;` you would get a no-match if the HTML comment has no newline.

Comment: FYI - The ask was for multiline only.